# Different vim indentation settings for specific file type

Tags: vim, indentation

Drupal provides some [reference](http://drupal.org/node/29325) on how to setup VIM for Drupal development, but I want these indentation settings to be applied to only drupal related files instead of all files

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

is that possible to set these settings to only .module and .inc files?

Not sure if this is relevant, but to provide syntax highlighting to the drupal files, I know the provided configuration would work

```
if has("autocmd")
  " Drupal *.module and *.install files.
  augroup module
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.module set filetype=php
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.install set filetype=php
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.test set filetype=php
  augroup END
endif
```

is it possible to put the settings above into this configuration block?

Comment: you can use `setlocal` for local buffer settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it would be possible, you said you want these settings to only apply to the *.module and *.inc file then I would modify your configuration block to look like this:

```
if has("autocmd")
  " Drupal *.module and *.install files.
  augroup module
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.module set filetype=php
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.install set filetype=php
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.test set filetype=php

    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.module set expandtab
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.module set tabstop=2
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.module set shiftwidth=2
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.module set autoindent
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.module set smartindent

    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.inc set expandtab
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.inc set tabstop=2
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.inc set shiftwidth=2
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.inc set autoindent
    autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.inc set smartindent

  augroup END
endif
```

Basically from my understanding of VIM is that almost anything that you can do in the .vimrc file can be done via the :prompt in vim such as **:set smartindent** for example.